# How to use MachineKey.Protect for a cookie?

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-4.5

I want to encrypt the ID that I am using in a cookie. I am using ASP.NET 4.5 so I want to use `MachineKey.Protect` to do it.

#### Code

```
    public static string Protect(string text, string purpose)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return string.Empty;
        
        byte[] stream = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
        byte[] encodedValue = MachineKey.Protect(stream, purpose);
        return HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(encodedValue);
    }

    public static string Unprotect(string text, string purpose)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return string.Empty;

        byte[] stream = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(text);
        byte[] decodedValue = MachineKey.Unprotect(stream, purpose);
        return HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(decodedValue);
    }
```

When I use the following test data:

`Protect()`:

> Input: 775119337
>
> Output: (Cookie) "HyV7ShLrb61cm9HWoHl2lUJtGMlMxLn60q27xwl7Ae1wpv31p7sJqfRDD8TMoSR8n8PPN1K7k7LsrjqWH6A-P17OblK3MApsDQRQLa8xj9A1"

`UnProtect()`:

> Output: "NwA3ADUAMQAxADkAMwAzADcA0"

The output isn't correct, of course, it should be the original ID I Input.

How do I get decrypt the cookie using `MachineKey.UnProtect()`?

Comment: You should probably use UTF8 for shorter strings.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`decodedValue` is the bytes you passed to `MachineKey.Protect()`.
This is not UrlTokenEncoded; it's Unicode-encoded bytes.

You need to call `Encoding.Unicode.GetString()`.

---

From the OP:

```
public static string Protect(string text, string purpose)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        return null;

    byte[] stream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    byte[] encodedValue = MachineKey.Protect(stream, purpose);
    return HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(encodedValue);
}

public static string Unprotect(string text, string purpose)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        return null;

    byte[] stream = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(text);
    byte[] decodedValue = MachineKey.Unprotect(stream, purpose);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. It helped me with Base64 errors that kept on getting thrown! There are a lot of other questions and answers related to this that I wish included your explanation.