# Increase timeout of an already started session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I want to add a "keep me logged in" option to my custom login control.

This is how I'm currently using the session:
I'm saving and reading values from `HttpContext.Current.Session["key"]` manually. Works fine.

Relevant parts of web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" useHostingIdentity="true" cookieless="false" timeout="120" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/login" name="AuthCookie" timeout="120" slidingExpiration="true" path="/" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
 <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

As you can see, the default duration of a session is 120 minutes.

**"Logout":**

```
  Session.Clear();
  Session.Abandon();
```

Through a custom login control with textboxes, I grant access to a member area. (I don't use `System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication`)
After entering valid credentials and a checked checkbox "keep logged in", I want to increase the duration of the already active session to ~30 days.

So far I've found solutions like

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket fat = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, "username", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1), false, "username");
string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(fat);
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket) { Expires = fat.Expiration });
```

which don't work, because System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Timeout is still at 120 minutes.
The same goes for setting

```
Session.Timeout = 666;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really approach it this way. You can't persist a session over days - it's just not going to scale well.

What most people do is provide a means for automatic login, so that when their session expires, they are seamlessly logged back in on the next action/reload. Most people do this with a cookie that contains a unique hash, which is checked at the server. If you want the person to be logged in for 30 days, you just set the cookie to expire in 30 days time.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I implemented it that way with an encrypted cookie.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out! Did you do it within the Forms Authentication framework? If so I'd love to hear/see details.

Comment: I added some details ;)

Answer (score 2):

I decided to give a short summary how I ended up doing it, because @David Haney asked me to:

I added a column to my usertable, which contains a GUID that is used for "relogging in" / giving credentials again. That GUID is created upon login and stored in the database.
It's also stored as an ecrypted value in a cookie. (My site doesn't use SSL)

**Added to Login routine** (if a user checked the "remeber me" checkbox):

```
HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("Session");
Guid sessionGuid =  // Buisiness layer call to generate value
String sessionID = sessionGuid.ToString();
aCookie.Value = Helper.Protect(sessionID, "sessionID");
aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```

where Helper.Protect and Helper.Unprotect are used from here  [How to use MachineKey.Protect for a cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618120/how-to-use-machinekey-protect-for-a-cookie) to store an encrypted and MAC signed value in a cookie.

Relogging is done by having every content page inherit from a class, that implements that logic and inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page`.

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
 {
    base.OnInit(e);

   if (Request.Cookies["Session"] != null && !CustomIsLoggedInCheckMethod)
   {
     String unprotected = Helper.Unprotect(Request.Cookies["Session"].Value, "sessionID");
     Guid sessionID = Guid.Parse(unprotected);
    // Calls to buisiness layer to get the user, set sessions values et cetera
   }
 }
}
```

If a user was banned after the last session or logs out, the cookie value expiration date will be set to a date in the past:

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("Session");
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

**Edit**:
Ah I forgot to mention this. I've also added a notification bar, that tells the user that he has been logged back in. It's based on http://blog.grio.com/2012/11/a-copypaste-ble-jquery-notification-bar.html
See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BdG2U/1/)

Comment: Nice, good approach. I have one thing to mention with it. If you ever scale your application beyond one server, your cookie will pose a problem. Because you've encrypted it with a signature of a particular server's MAC, the next server in the round-robin to process the cookie may not be able to decrypt it. For that reason I'd consider a "shared secret" model where all servers use a secret key to encrypt/decrypt via AES. Nice work!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it. Yesterday I've seen another user asking a question about server farms and the Protect/Unprotect methods and the solution was to force every server in the server farm to use the same MachineKey. I guess that would work, if my site ever scales that big =)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I added visual mention of being logged back in ;)